# How can I get input field in iframe?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use the below code to get input field in web page,

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input [ type = "text"]');
```

However, today I found the code can't work in specific condition, and found:

The input field in the webpage can't be seen in "View Source Page" in Firefox, but if I use Firebug, I can see that an iframe is injected into a div tag, and the iframe contains the input field.(this iframe doesn't exist in "View Source Page")

I use Fiddler and found: the iframe code is from another response, which is after the first response.( these response are from the same origin.)

My question is: how can I get the input field in the iframe?

I am new to JavaScript, so apologizing if it's a dumb question.

Comment: remove the double quotes from text.
 var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
but I am not sure, you can do anything with iframe code.

Comment: Is the content in that iframe is from different origin?

Comment: These http responses are from the same origin.

Comment: well then u can use JS to access the iframe document.

Comment: Could you give me an example code?